# Excel VSTO Autofilter not working right?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm working on a Excel VSTO project with Office & VS 2010. I have the code to get a range but I can't seem to get the Autofilter to work right. Heres the code I have so far:

```
Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisWorkbook.InnerObject;
Excel.Name rngN = wb.Names.Item("MyNamedRange", System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
Excel.Range rng = rngN.RefersToRange;
int allRows = rng.Rows.Count;
rng.AutoFilter(8, "ST", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr, System.Type.Missing, null);
int filteredRows = rng.Rows.Count;
```

However, in this example, the row counts are identical and my range is not filtered at all - Im referring to the variables **allRows** and **filteredRows** above. So I'm either not implementing the filter correctly and or my filter statement is wrong. My filter line:

```
rng.AutoFilter(8, "ST", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr, System.Type.Missing, null);
```

So my understanding is that this line would look for all matches of "ST" in the 8th field. Is that not correct? Why are my record counts the same?

Comment: I would try removing the xlOr argument with `System.Type.Missing` as it is an optional argument. Also note that the columns are indexed from 1 in Excel.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm aware of the 1-based index and I have removed those parameters to no avail. Any other ideas please?

Comment: The cells don't have extra spaces do they "ST " ? Check that the parent of rng is the correct worksheet: `rng.Parent.Name`

Comment: Please see my comments to your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the second part of your question, getting the number of filtered rows is tricky. `rng.Rows.Count` will return the original number of rows, not the filtered number.

You can use an expression like the following:

```
Evaluate("=SUBTOTAL(3," & Range("A:A").Address & ")-1")
```

which you can store in an integer - you may have to cast the result.

3 represents the COUNTA function (excluding the filtered rows) and I'm subtracting 1 to exclude the header row. Increase this number if there are other occupied cells in the column.

You could store this formula temporarily in a cell, but I believe it should return a result using `Evaluate()`.

**Added** Read

```
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

before and after applying the filter to determine whether the filter worked.

There is useful information about Excel filtering at this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd795215%28v=office.11%29.aspx#odc_office2007_taWorkingwithListsTablesPart2_FilteraTableorList).

Comment: So it IS possible that my filter is working right but my reliance on the count as proof of the filter is wrong, correct? So is there no way to access the filtered range? Eventually I need the values that are contained within the filtered range programatically - I'm assuming thats possible, no?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I suppose you could save and close the file and later open it to see if the filter is in-place. Added: You might access the filtered data using `rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Comment: Yup,that did it! Thank you, that got me so much further along. Now, one more part to this. I'm assuming its possible to add multiple filters like rng.AutoFilter(8, "ST") and immediately after rng.AutoFilter(8, "HT"), right?

Comment: @JimBeam Yes. It is always helpful to record a quick macro in Excel, which, if you select more than one item in the filter-list, produces: `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$L$112").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Accounts", "Admin", "IT"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: @JimBeam I've added a useful link to my answer.